# detecting and displaying usb camera in Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am wondering how to detect any webcam connected to my mac and display it on my Mac OSX application? should i do a path search for `/dev` connected devices? and if so, how would i come to read output from the port or activate the foreign camera?

Comment: As always, use the API designed for such things. That way you'll find any camera the system cares about.

Answer (score 2):

You should be working with high-level APIs for this. If you're targetting OS X 10.7 and later, use AVFoundation's `AVCaptureSession` class. If you need to support Mac OS X 10.6 and earlier, use QuickTime's `QTCaptureDevice` class. Both are well-documented on http://developer.apple.com/mac/.